# How to check if .war is deployed in ASW Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to learn AWS and I tried to deploy a webapp in AWS Elastic Beanstalk with following command.

`be deploy`

The output of this command gives successful message.Now, where can I see if my webapp is actually deployed in Beanstalk? Is there any GUI which displays what webapps are deployed (the way we can see in an web-container, for example in tomcat).

When i try to access the URL, i get 404 message.

PS: I am a newbie to AWS, so if any detailed message i get, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You get to see the UI In AWS Management Console -- Elastic Beanstalk.

Please Follow this [Basic Tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/deploy/setting-up.html)

Hope This Helps.